# Custome MessageBox under Tab(s) ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, messagebox

I like to separate MessageBox tab to tab. One MessageBox will shown in one particular tab and will hidden from all other tab(s). What is now show as global in application. Is there any way to show message under every tab(s) in application.

Comment: Please provide code that can cover your example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a messagebox with different content on the separate tabs at the same time while messagebox is a singleton, but you can create your own messagebox, extending from Window and render each instance to the separate tab. Here is [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vf4) with native Window, but it will work the same with extended component.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use `Ext.window.MessageBox` to achieve what you want. On the other hand, you can create a small utility class that extends `Ext.window.Window`, with a static function that makes it appear with the title, message, and buttons as parameters, and use the `constrainTo` option to make it belong to your tab.

This way, you have a window that can be "owned" by a tab instead of appearing globally

Answer (score 0):

Here i create a function to show message as messagebox. And i can use it whatever i need.

```
ShowPrivateMessage: function(title, widthValue, heightValue, msgText, renderTabId){
    Ext.create("Ext.window.Window",{
        title : title,
        width : widthValue,
        height: heightValue,
        html : '<span style="font-size: small">'+ msgText + '</span>',
        renderTo: renderTabId,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,

        bodyPadding: '10px',
        listeners:{
            afterrender: function(sender, eOpt){
                var parentWindow = Ext.getCmp(renderTabId);
                parentWindow.disable();
            }
            ,close: {
                fn:function(ctrl,opt){
                    var parentWindow = Ext.getCmp(renderTabId);
                    parentWindow.enable();
                }
            }
        }
    }).show();
}
```